# Rails: how to get records based on user interests from my current associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, database-schema, model-associations

I have this relationship:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :activities
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips
  has_many :user_interests
  has_many :interests, through: :user_interests
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_interests
  has_many :users, through: :user_interests
end
```

Users are able to select certain types of interests, and these Trips have activities tagged with them. I want to be able to get records of the Trips that has certain activities that the user are interested.

I've been testing some things out like this:

`= Trip.all.to_json` (sees all the Trip records) and `= current_user.interests.to_son` (sees what current user interested in) just to test if it works... and it does.

Is it possible to get only the trips that the users are interested in?

Comment: Is there any relationship between trip and interests?

Comment: what are activities and what is the relation between them and user?

Comment: @TriveniBadgujar just the activities tag, I've set it up where users can only insert the name of the activities through an autocomplete (from the interest). So activities and interests have the same names.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko activities are just tagged and users can only type in the activities from the interests. So if the app has only "bike" interest, then if user creates a trip, the activity field will have "bike" and they can only insert bike into that field.

Comment: `current_user.joins(:trips, :user_interests).where('trips.user_id = user_interests.user_id').trips`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume Interest model has name attribute and now question is to find all trips to which user is interested for.

As you are using `acts_as_taggable on` gem, you can do something like -

```
Trip.tagged_with(user.interests.pluck(:name), on: :activities, any: true)
```

Comment: Yes, this one is simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this query:

```
Trip.includes('user_interests').where('trip.user_id = user_interests.user_id').references(:user_interests)
```

This will give you all trips where users are interested.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find trips where `trip->activities` match `user->interests`?
Assuming your Interest model has `name` attribute, the following works:

```
Trip.includes(taggings: :tag).where(tags: {name: current_user.interests.pluck(:name)})
```

I will advise you to encapsulate this as method in your User model like the following:

```
class User > ActiveRecord::Base
  #..
  #..

  def trips_interested_in
    Trip.includes(taggings: :tag).where(tags: {name: self.interests.pluck(:name)})
  end
end
```

So that you could call:

```
trips = @user.trips_interested_in
```

And/Or you could also add this as a scope in the Trip model like the following:

```
class Trip > ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :where_user_is_interested_in, ->(user) { includes(taggings: :tag).where(tags: {name: user.interests.pluck(:name)}) }

  #..
  #..
end
```

So you could also call:

```
trips = Trip.where_user_is_interested_in(@user)
```